# Parameterization for this surface integral

Tags: calculus, integration, surface-integrals, parametrization

The problem is:

Evaluate the $\int \int_SF* dS$ for the given vector field F and the oriented surface S. for closed surfaces, use the positive (outward) orientation. F(x,y,z) = xi +yj +5k. S is the boundary of the region enclosed by the cylinder $x^2 + z^2$ = 1 and the planes y = 0 and x + y = 2.

I get that these are three separate surfaces. The only one I'm having trouble with is the lateral portion of the cylinder. In my book, they parametrize it as x = sin(t), y=y, z=cos(t). Why do they have x as sin and z cos? Is there a way to have x as cos and z as sin and just change the bounds?

Comment: is there a typo here? $x+y=2$ is a superfluous bound to the one given for the cylinder and $z$ is unconstrained.

Comment: @qbert yeah sorry.  The cylinder was supposed to be $x^2 + z^2$ = 1. I've fixed it

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP will surely have had the lectures by now that cover the divergence theorem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question *has two* good answers to which OP should have reacted.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the divergence theorem? It is particularly easy in this case
since 
$$
\nabla\cdot F=2
$$
Reducing your surface integral to 
$$
2\int\int\int_V dzdxdy=2\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-z^2}}^{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\int_0^{2-x}dydxdz
$$
where $V$ is the volume described. Note that this is easier in cylindrical coordinates (how the solution is proceeding), where we allow $\theta$ to sweep out the full cylinder, the radius is from $0$ to $1$, and your integral is
$$
2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^{2-2r\cos \theta}rdydrd\theta\\
=2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1(2r-r^2\cos \theta)dydrd\theta\\
=2\int_0^{2\pi}(1-1/3\cos \theta)d\theta\\
=4\pi
$$

Comment: We haven't done divergence theorem yet.  I think thats in two lectures

Answer (score 0):

Setting either $(x,z)=(\cos t,\sin t)$ or $(x,z)=(\sin t,\cos t)$ is fine, since both satisfy $x^2+z^2=1$. However, in the $(x,z)$ plane, the first choice parameterizes a circular arc starting at $(1,0)$ and encircling the origin in the counterclockwise direction, while the second choice parameterizes the same arc but starting at $(0,1)$ and directed clockwise. As you're integrating a vector field over $S$, you'll need to correctly decide which normal vector to use.

With the **first choice**, we parameterize the lateral wall $S_L$ of the cylinder by

$$\vec s_1 (t,y) = \cos t\,\vec\imath + y\,\vec\jmath + \sin t\,\vec k , \quad t\in[0,2\pi] \land y\in[0,2-\cos t]$$

and the outward-pointing normal is given by

$$\vec n = \frac{\partial\vec s_1}{\partial \color{red}y} \times \frac{\partial\vec s_1}{\partial t} = \cos t\,\vec\imath + \sin t\,\vec k$$

Then the integral across $S_L$ is

$$\iint_{S_L} \vec F \cdot \vec n \, dS = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2-\cos t} \left(\cos^2t + 5\sin t\right) \, dy \, dt$$

On the other hand, with the **second choice** we have

$$\vec s_2 (t,y) = (\sin t, y, \cos t), \quad t\in[0,2\pi], y\in[0,2-\sin t]$$

with normal vector

$$\vec n = \frac{\partial\vec s_2}{\partial t} \times \frac{\partial\vec s_2}{\partial \color{red}y} = \sin t\,\vec\imath + \cos t\,\vec k$$

but we end up with a similar integral,

$$\iint_{S_L} \vec F\cdot\vec n\,dS = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2-\sin t} \left(\sin^2t + 5\cos t\right) \, dy \, dt$$

Either way we get the same value.